# Meeting potential interviewer in social situation

Tags: interviewing, socializing

My friend was offered an interview for a job at a company that his friend works for (his friend is one of the interviewers as well), but turned it down as he had just started a new job. He told his friend (the interviewer) that he had a friend name MooseLucifer that would be interested, and told me I should apply. I submitted an application immediately but haven't heard anything yet (but it's only been 1 business day).

Today, my friend invited me to grab some drinks and go go-karting with him and the interviewer, whom I've never met. I'm a car guy, and the job for a design engineer at a car place, so I'm pretty confident we'll get along fine, but how should I approach the situation?

- Should I be treating it like a pseudo-interview?
- I work as a manufacturing engineer and usually dress very casually, should I dress nicer?
- Assuming they don't call me to schedule an interview before then, He knows I applied and am awaiting a call, should I ask about an interview? Should I pretext the interaction by saying "don't worry about it, whether you want to interview me or not is a professional decision, and I totally understand if I don't make the cut" or something like that?
- I'm pretty smart about reserving inappropriate jokes around a new person until they have shown if they're okay with them or not, but having a mutual friend there will definitely help with that. Either way, cars/racing makes for a pretty testosterone-y environment, and the jokes are usually pretty lude, should I avoid them or might it help my chances?

Comment: There is no scenario in which an inappropriate joke can help you. Don't.

Comment: @keshlam I guess an inappropriate joke, by definition, is not appropriate for any situation, but I can see being able to make the interviewer laugh as helpful, and it might help check the 'this guy would fit in with office/garage folks' box. Either way, I agree I should probably be a little more *Weird Al* and a little less *Stephen Lynch* (who has a song titled 'Dead Puppies').

Answer (score 6):

For sure you don't say anything about not making the cut.

Just treat it as a social interaction and if they ask an interview type question then answer.

No one go-karts in a suit.

If alcohol then limit your drinks.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and good point about the suit haha. I'll probably ask my friend if he has to wear a dress shirt at his new gig, if we're both dressed casually I won't stand out.

Comment: *No one go-karts in a suit.* - strangely insightful.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should just be yourself.

This doesn't sound like a proxy interview. You shouldn't need to dress up, and you shouldn't initiate conversation about your pending application.

Your friend or the interviewer may bring it up. Again, just be yourself.

I would probably watch my language and avoid potentially offensive topics (politics, religion, etc.)

And lastly, as Paparazzi mentioned, don't drink and/or keep it to a minimum.